# How do I automatically create Django relationship when an object is created?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want a user to be able to create a `Store` object. When it is created, it should automatically create the `EmploymentRelationship` type as `Owner` for this user/store combination. At a later point the `Owner` of a store is able to add `Employee`. How do I make this initial relationship though when the object is created in the administration interface?

```
class Store(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField('Description of Store',max_length=45, null=False, blank=False)

class EmploymentRelationship(models.Model):
    OWNERTYPECHOICES = (
        (constants.OWNER, 'Owner'),
        (constants.EMPLOYEE, 'Employee'),
    )

    sid = models.ForeignKey(Store, null=False, blank=False)
    uid = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False)
    employment_type = models.IntegerField('Ownership Type',default=constants.EMPLOYEE, choices=OWNERTYPECHOICES)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override save_model in your admin class:

```
class StoreAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(StoreAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        if not change:
            EmploymentRelationship.objects.create(
                sid=obj, uid=request.user, employment_type=constants.OWNER)
```

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model).